# Inquiry comment deleted for no apparent reason: clarifying if there is any malicious intent with my comment deletion

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation, deleted-comments

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414501/how-to-let-the-ide-know-that-i-use-ancestor-variable), and to no surprise, received a downvote. That's not the problem, it happens all the time. And I somewhat understand the reason for the downvote - even though technically I did still answer the question in its state at that time.

Once I noticed the downvote, I commented along the lines of "Would the downvoter please explain? This answer would have been correct if OP hadn't excluded certain information in their question."

I just noticed that particular comment has been deleted. And I have no idea why. All the other comments appear to remain.

It's my understanding (at least in the past) that moderators are only able to delete all comments, or delete one in response to somebody reporting it for abuse. Yet I don't see why it would have been reported, or have any issue, especially since OP respectfully responded to it (among other people).

I have a feeling that the moderator who deleted it is the same person who downvoted the answer. I don't like to jump to conclusions, but that's what it seems like.

Can someone explain what rule is in place that permits moderators to specifically delete individual comments, despite the fact that it was a simple inquiry as to the reason for the downvote, and was not in any way condescending or rude?

Fundamentally, if I'm not allowed to learn and improve my future answers by asking such questions in comments, then where should I ask? The ideal solution would be to get direct feedback from that person who found a reason to downvote. Stack Overflow is supposed to be about improving the future quality of information. How can I help do that if I can't ask how to improve?

---

**EDIT** Based on responses, it seems as if *any* comment can be deleted by *any* user by simply flagging it. Is this the case?

Comment: It was flagged by someone as “no longer needed” and a moderator deleted it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So, someone on SO thought that I no longer need to improve my answers to make the community better in the future?

Comment: To be a moderator, at least in my humble opinion, means to have a good understanding of what's happening, to look at the context, and judge whether action is appropriate. I see this as a mod taking quick and immediate action on something with zero thought. That's not what moderation is about.

Comment: @JerryDodge I'll look at your account right now. In future you can raise a mod flag. Be assured, moderators are scrutinized heavily - all our actions are logged as well as any access to PII. We scrutinize each other, plus we have the employees scrutinizing us. Let me check your account. Always raise a flag for serial downvoting - but always give the automatic script time to reverse them

Comment: The saddest thing I take from this post is this: **"I answered a question, and to no surprise, received a downvote. That's not the problem, it happens all the time. "** It is hard when people are doing their best to contribute to the site to met with continuous downvotes. :/

Comment: related: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/839601)

Comment: To give some more context: I generally delete flagged “to the downvoter”  comments because the voter is almost *never there anymore to read it*. When one of my own answers receives a downvote and the question I’m answering is “fresh” and I’ve triple-checked my answer, I ask in a comment if anyone might be willing to provide feedback I can use to improve my answer. I just don’t address this to the voter. That comment is also obsolete within the hour, when other answerers (experts with insight into what I could have done wrong) are gone too.

Comment: In this specific case, your comment had been up for over 15 hours before it was flagged, and was close to 16 hours old when a moderator handled the flag.

Comment: There also appears to be some confusion over the term “moderator”, and who can remove comments.  There are no [elected moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) (accounts with a ♦️ diamond next to their display name that are not Stack Overflow staff), that are frequent Delphi answerers, so whomever you are suspecting is probably not a moderator. Only accounts with a diamond can delete anyone’s comments, and we generally only do so when those comments have been flagged for some reason and we agree that the flag has merit.

Comment: Looking at your answer, it is partially wrong, so this may be reason why someone down voted. You stated "This is just the nature of inheritance, more specifically, field visibility" while actually problem is in IDE that does not properly recognize protected field that should be visible. Of course, that does not explain why would someone flag your comment asking about clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's my understanding (at least in the past) that moderators are only able to delete all comments, or delete one in response to somebody reporting it for abuse.

Nope.

Mods can delete any comments that come to their attention, whether through flags or using the site, that they feel are unnecessary or inappropriate. They can choose to move a chain of comments to chat, delete an entire chain, or delete individual comments from a chain without touching any of the others.

When it comes to flags, feel free to click the flag icon on any comment to see the choices for flagging. One of those reasons is "no longer needed". This flag is specifically designed for comments that are either now obsolete due to having served their purpose or were never useful.

With your specific comment, if it helps, imagine that the downvoter flagged it as no longer needed because they have no interest in responding to it. I don't know that this is the case with your specific comment but it may give you some peace of mind that it served its purpose and why it was removed.

Comment: "imagine that the downvoter flagged it as no longer needed because they have no interest in responding to it." That's exactly the issue I'm trying to bring into light. I know at least 1 moderator who heavily follows the `delphi` tag who has a lot of personal issues with me. Moderation shouldn't be about personal opinion.

Comment: A mod didn't flag your comment, as George already explained.

Comment: So, does that mean any comment can be deleted by any user by simply flagging it?

Comment: @JerryDodge: 1) Downvoters are never required to explain their downvotes. That's how the system works, and whether your comment is deleted or not won't change things. 2) If you believe there is a pattern of the same user downvoting you repeatedly, that is a separate issue, which can (probably) only be resolved by flagging one of your own questions that you suspect is affected and explaining the problem. It will then be escalated to Stack Overflow employees. I recommend waiting 24 hours first, though, because that gives time for the automation to catch obvious cases.

Comment: @Kevin #1 of course I don't expect that to be a requirement. That wasn't the issue. I don't care if I never get a response. But the fact that my inquiry was deleted while everybody else's comments stayed is the issue.

Comment: @JerryDodge That's less a matter of targeting than how the flag handling interface works. Only the flagged comment is shown to them. Unless the comment seems like part of a chain, the mod is unlikely to realize there are other comments. Even still, if someone is already talking to you about the issues with your answer, your comment asking for explanations is no longer necessary. If you feel that the comments still on the answer have been addressed, flag them!

Comment: Indeed, I guess it would help if I could see how moderators are presented with flagged comments. That would make better sense. Now I'm questioning why mods only see the single comment itself, and can take immediate action on the spot, rather than taking a look at the context of that comment.

Comment: "Why was I downvoted?" Type comments are some of the most commonly deleted comments on posts. Mods probably delete dozens per day. If you want help improving your post, there may be better ways of asking for that... and that starts with not asking the voter. You may have better luck by trying something like "based on my reading of the question, this should be the correct answer. If I've misunderstood something, please let me know and I can clarify."

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that coming from newer users on their questions. But on answers that have been accepted since then, it's still very odd to me.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding why people are so attached to their comments.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It's not the comment itself which I'm concerned about. It's the nature in why/who deleted it. The same mod who I *believed* took action is also seen on that same question.

Comment: @JerryDodge I handled the flag on that comment and deleted it! Do you want me to proceed to investigate your account? Just checking I'm not the mod you are wary of/

Comment: @YvetteColomb Welp then that seems unnecessary.  Thanks for taking a look and confirming that.

Comment: @JerryDodge The answer was accepted after the downvote. That it was downvoted is frustrating but you have upvotes and an accepted checkmark. I am somewhat confused, though. I don't see any action on the question or answer by a diamond moderator at all (other than handling the flags).

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm sending a message re your account to the community team  to look at the voting. There is no moderator who has given you serial downvotes. If you  feel like you cannot trust a moderator - raise a custom mod flag, name the moderator - we can handle the criticism and then someone can check for you. The mod named will not handle it - we try to avoid conflict of interests

Comment: By the way, I checked said person's profile, and while I thought they were a mod, they aren't. I guess it's just having that high rep with many privileges which lead me to believe they were a mod. I should get myself a jumping to conclusions mat.

Comment: @JerryDodge we can all have those. Can you please raise a flag with your concerns? You can use any post, just link the user's profile in your flag.

Comment: @YvetteColomb If I see further concern, I will. This was all a mix of different things, the specific person only being part of the issue. If I see that person being for sure a problem, I'll flag them. I don't want to bother people who might not actually be related. But I felt that *someone* was abusing their privileges here.

Comment: @JerryDodge no worries, sometimes just having those types of suspicions allayed is half the battle. I have sent off an enquiry to the community team in he mean time to check for voting irregularities. They can see more detail than the mods can and can get a better idea if votes are vengeful or not when it may not be clear to us, Don't hesitate to reach out in future.

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume that the comment was flagged.  If it was, it'd qualify instantly for removal, since it adds little value to the actual answer itself.

Comments are ephemeral by design; they can disappear for any reason at any time.  Having a comment asking for someone to explain their downvote is often begging for some kind of sidebar discussion on the merits of your answer over their opinion of it, which wouldn't be germane to your actual answer.

Comment: I clearly understand comments aren't permanent, and can be deleted forever at any time. But the nature of the comment shouldn't have constituted a flag/report. I've had issues with serial-downvoters in the past, and I think it might be the same person. I won't give names unless it's asked. But I know this person is currently a moderator.

Comment: I just wanted to understand the reason for the downvote so that I could learn and improve my answers in the future.