# Is it now common to delete most comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I recently participated in a brief comment stream on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57617037/37572

I then came back a few hours later, and saw that all but one comment had been deleted. I realise the comments weren't all particularly interesting, but from memory they were all on topic. I remember something similar happening on another question I was involved in recently.

I have been to many answers over the years and seen many nuggets of gold in comments that relate to what I'm interested in even if it is not exactly what the OP was about. It would be a shame if deleting tangential comments became normal.

So is the norm now to purge all but the most relevant comments?

Comment: Were the posts edited based on insights gained from comments? If yes, they could have been flagged as "no longer needed".

Comment: @ModusTollens Yes the answer was edited due to comments, so I understand now.  Thanks.  Also, I'm afraid I must really misunderstand Meta, since I got a downvote so quick.  Is this really not a Meta question?

Comment: Sometimes downvotes on meta mean that users disagree, maybe that was the reason here. In my opinion it's a valid meta question.

Comment: The comments were flagged as "no longer needed" after the post was edited. If you don't agree that the edit resolved your comment, feel free to re-add your comment, or perhaps consider posting a better answer.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thanks.  I'm not concerned with those particular comments.  It was intended to be a general question about accepted practice.

Comment: Comments have always been second class citizens, easily deleted. The policy has not changed here.

Comment: I just don't understand the negativity to this genuine question.  Could some people give me some constructive advice about why this question is so unpopular instead of simply voting?  It's not that I'm complaining about my comments being deleted, just asking about policy.

Comment: @ModusTollens It's not really possible to disagree with a question... "no, I don't agree that you are asking this" or what?

Comment: It reads a bit passive-aggressive which we, the 0,015% of SO users that visit meta, have had enough of that tone in posts in the last 6 to 8 months. On top of that, glancing over your question you seem to suggest that comments shouldn't be so easily deleted. The consensus on that point is different. So some votes certainly try to tell future visitors: comments are to be purged at any time, rather sooner then later.

Comment: @Lundin "No, it is not now common to delete most comments" See "Voting is different on meta" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @ModusTollens That's not disagreement, that's an opinion-based answer to the question.

Comment: @rene Fair enough.  It was not intended to be passive-aggressive, although I agree it included my opinion.  Thanks. o-o

Comment: @Lundin Look, I don't want to argue, I'm just informing you that some users vote differently on meta. I didn't and I don't agree it should be done on this question. I just mentioned it as a possibility.

Comment: It is not uncommon to have people coming to Meta to ask why their comments are gone. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388405/1233251) is another example, and the answer within also seems to apply here.

Comment: "It's not that I'm complaining about my comments being deleted, just asking about policy." The question does not show much research effort. Did you do anything to try to find out what the comment deletion policy is currently? I actually upvoted, but only because it was downvoted so much.

Comment: @JohnRees The terminology "passive agressive" is often used argument against unpleasant truths, and is only rarely fair.

Comment: @JohnRees: On the other hand, the user that is accused of being "passive-aggressive" often isn't the best judge of how that comment is perceived. _"unpleasant truths"_ is rhetoric usually employed by the "aggressor" ;-)

Comment: TBH I came here to ask about stackoverflow practices rather than psychoanalysis. I think I’ll stick to the main site. This is too much of a minefield.

Comment: @JohnRees Between the meta sites, the MSO community represents least its main site community: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1095336/site-by-relative-meta-activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is the norm now to purge all but the most relevant comments?

There are currently 75 million comments on Stack Overflow, and I saw in chat somewhere that moderators do delete quite a lot of them (<100k comments deleted for one moderator in <2 years?), but that would be nowhere near enough to reduce the numbers of existing comments drastically. Considering that every year millions of comments are added, I would say that statistically there is no evidence for a large-scale purge of comments. It may have been an isolated, rather infrequent incident.

<sub>In the comments there was some kind of rant (now deleted) by someone, whose name I don't remember, that expressed the opinion that deletion of comments could be criminal. Probably that is not true, maybe he or she just wanted to express disagreement with deletion of comments. Surely, with the heavy load of comments that get deleted by moderators, mistakes are bound to happen and one can even disagree with the general direction of where this is going. But in the end, moderators also do a lot of good - it's always a personal weighting of all things to consider whether one should support the current practice or not.</sub>

Comment: This might be a similar effect of some  people wondering "why so many downvotes": a false perception of scale. Even multiplying 100k by 26 moderators makes 2.6 million comments, which is significantly less than the number of comments posted in 2018 alone (approx 8.2 million).

Answer (score -17):

I also have seen that sometimes very important comments also deleted either by a moderator or anyone who has permission to do it.

If I know if any questions/answer had very important comments but now deleted, I use a custom flag (in need of moderator intervention flag) to notify the moderators. I have done it a few times and every time moderators have undeleted them.

Comment: _"or anyone who has permission to do it."_ Only moderators, employees, and comment owners can delete comments. Moderators can not undelete comments that were deleted by the comment's author.

Comment: @Cerbrus and there is the list with "trigger" words that make comments go poof with one or a couple of flags.

Comment: @rene Trigger words? What are they?

Comment: @Dharman It is a [secret](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238835/what-is-the-se-version-of-seven-dirty-words), sorry.